# Premiere failing to export long video "file does not exist" error

Tags: premiere, adobe, cc-2015

I'm trying to export a long (2h20m) video interview from Premiere CC 2015 on a mac for translation purposes.

The source video is ProRes 422 mov files

I'm adding timecode & source file name effects as overlays

The export is to h264, Vimeo preset.

I've tried HD 1920x1080p, and SD 480p

Every time, the export fails with the error "file does not exist".

See screen shots:
[image: screenshot1]
[image]

Comment: Looks like a bug. Might be a good idea to report it: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/878528, https://bugbase.adobe.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it as a two-step process:

1. Export your movie with the identical format as your sequence, using a reasonable high-quality ProRes format as your output (so you don't suffer much the damage of double-compression)
2. Compress the output of Step 1 into the format and codec you like

Premiere Pro and Adobe Media Encoder have all kinds of problems right now, and not only with El Capitan.  Many others have hit the same glitch you have, both on Yosemite and El Capitan, with or without hardware rendering.  CC2015 has been a big disappointment to many.

Comment: If the OP is willing to use an external encoder then using a frameserver from within Premiere will save him one encoding pass i.e. the export from out of Premiere. This is a frameserver that I've used - http://www.debugmode.com/frameserver/